# Azure storage connection string without the account key - public containers

Tags: azure, storage, blob, acl

I am having a blob container which ACL is set up to allow full public read access so anyone can read and list the blobs in that container.

I store the files so the WPF client app my clients use could read them but I don't want to allow them to modify/delete/create files.

**Does anyone knows what connection string should be used in this scenario?**

I hoped to specify the connection string without the account key and/or shared access key due to the fact blobs are public but that didn't work - StorageAccount.Parse throws FormatException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the previous answers, the best practice is usually to control the access to your blob container using shared access signatures (SAS) or a stored access policy. These can be used to create an access token (string) you can pass to your client without revealing your account key.

However, it is also possible to specify the level of public read access to the blobs and metadata saved in the container. Public access is the level of read permission automatically given an anonymous user that is in possession the public access url for the container or blob. You cannot use public access to give anonymous users write permissions to the container.  If you need to give write permission to users that are not in possession of the account key of your Azure storage account, then you will need to provide those users with a token in the form of a url the references a shared access signature or a shared access policy. 
If the public access to the blob container is not currently off (private,) anonymous user will be able to read all blobs in the container using a public access url such as the following.

```
http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net/container1/image2.jpg
```

When you create the container, you can set the value of the publicAccess property  to the appropriate constant of the  BlobContainerPublicAccessType enum.  The value of the publicAccess property can be one of the following three constants which specify the level of public read access.

• BLOB – The public can read the content and metadata of blobs within this container, but cannot read container metadata or list the blobs within the container.

• CONTAINER – The public can read blob content and metadata and container metadata, and can list the blobs within the container.

• OFF – Specifies no public access. Only the account owner can read resources in this container.

So in this case the public access level might be set to CONTAINER.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException 
   {            
   Account creds = new Account();               
   final String storageConnectionString = creds.getstorageconnectionstring();
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("container1");
   container.createIfNotExist();
   BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
   containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);
   container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
   BlobContainerPublicAccessType access1 = containerPermissions.getPublicAccess();
   System.out.println("Public access to " + container.getName() + " is set to: 
      " + access1);
  }
```

If the public access level on container1 has been set to CONTAINER, an anonymous user should be able to list the blobs in container1 knowing only the storage account AccountName ("grassy") and the container name, but without needing to know the AccountKey. For example, an anonymous application might use java code similar to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException, FileNotFoundException, IOException 
   {            
   URI baseuri = new URI("http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net");
   CloudBlobClient blobclient = new CloudBlobClient(baseuri);
   CloudBlobContainer container = blobclient.getContainerReference("container1");   
      for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()){System.out.println(blobItem.getUri());}   
   }
```

However, as discussed, it is a better practice to avoid giving anonymous users access. Instead control access to the container using a SAS or policy and pass on the token to only known users.

Comment: MArk, that's exactly my use case - I have a container with CONTAINER access policy which allows all of the users to list and download the data - completely agree with what you wrote.

My question is related to the scenario that that all of my clients have WPF applications which have to list *files* in that container during the 1st startup of the app, pull all of the scripts etc list finds out and perform some activity with it. The problem is that as of this moment I don't know what to put in app.config file as a container connection string because AFAIK even for PUBLIC CONTAINERS - key needed

Comment: See the update to my answer. The added code snippet should enable any anonymous user to list the blobs in the container.

Comment: Ok, your code based solution lead me to try to set the connection string in configuration file to simple     
<add name="storageConnectionString" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http; AccountName=containerName;" /> and that (obviously) worked - thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to you.

Comment: @MarkRovetta, why it is a better practice to avoid giving anonymous users access? Especially read access? Isn't the point of public files to be accessible from public? Or it is because Azure is insecure?

Answer (score 1):

StorageAccount is not meant to connect to public blobs as far as I know.  You simply can get at the public blobs via public URL by using something like [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or any other tool that can download data over public http/https endpoint.

Comment: The reason why I want to have my WPF client app directly accessing the BLOB is to avoid all the traffic going through my web server and use Azure itself to scale out file transfers without perf issues caused to my web site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shared access signature for that purpose. What you could do is create the SAS on a blob container which only allows list and read permissions on the blob container and then distribute that SAS URI to your clients. Your code could then create an instance of `BlobContainer` object using that SAS URI.

Here's the sample code for listing blobs in a blob container using SAS URI:

```
static void ListBlobsWithStorageClientLibrary(string blobContainerSasUri)
{
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(blobContainerSasUri));
    var blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs(null, true);
    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri);
    }
}
```

Other alternative is to create an instance of `StorageCredentials` object using SAS token: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj682529.aspx. Then you could create an instance of `CloudStorageAccount` object using that StorageCredentials object.

I wrote a detailed post on using Shared Access Signatures with blob storage which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/

Comment: I am aware of SAS but it is PUBLIC container - if I give you the plain url, and you type it in your browser you'll get the file - no problem at all. Second thing here is that if my web site is down there is no way to issue them a token. My design goal is to provide them with cloud stored document which always work with minimal risk of failure - preferably I want to depend only on Azure blob storage availability.